# Skipping bad JSON data in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson data binding, what's the neatest way to skip a bad chunk of data, *without rejecting the whole parse*?

Take these classes (I'm using public fields just to keep the code short):

```
 public class ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction {
     public ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction(String s) {
         if(s.charAt(0) > 'L') {
            throw new BadParameterException();
         }
         // else init code here.
     }
 }

 public class User {
     public String name;
     public ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction failable;
 }

 public class AppInfo {
     public List<User> users;
 }
```

... and this code to parse it:

```
 AppInfo appinfo = (List<User>) objectMapper.readValues(jsonStream, AppInfo.class);
```

... and this JSON:

```
 { "users": [ 
     { "name": "John", "failable": "Example" },
     { "name": "Jane", "failable": "No good" }
   ]
 }
```

By default `ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction("No good")` will throw an exception which will bubble up to the caller of `objectMapper.readValues()`.

- How can I make it return a `AppInfo` object containing a `users` list that is **one item long** (the valid item)?
- And can I run a routine to deal with (e.g. to log) the skipped entry?

I know I can achieve this with a custom deserializer:

```
 public class User {
     public String name;
     @JsonDeserialize (using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
     public ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction failable;
 }
```

... in which MyCustomDeserializer consumes the content in incremental mode. I'm looking for an option which takes advantage of data binding. Consider that `ClassWhichCouldFailConstruction` might be something a whole lot more complicated, so writing a custom parser would be laborious.

Comment: Your custom deserializer could internally use its own `ObjectMapper`, and return `null` if that mapper threw an exception.

Comment: if you need to validate the JSON message you might have a look at [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/), though it is still in draft and has its limits (no object-orientated like inheritance but a kind of by using `allOf` a referenced schema, though you can't override those reference values - so the JSON message is validated against both schemas - a bit tricky but other than that it works)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bean Validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/) instead of throwing exception from constructor -- aspects of JSON parsing and data-binding (that Jackson does) can be separated from validation logic. This is where Bean Validator helps: you can declaratively define rules and constraints.

Comment: Can you explain how that would be used to achieve the goal described? That is, to skip the invalid part of a JSON parse, letting the rest of it through.

Comment: You would not do that, but rather you would not embed validation deep within your objects but use Bean Validation annotations for declarative approach (or, for more complex cases, implement validators that are associated using annotations).

If you do want to skip values that throw exception, you better create custom `JsonDeserializer` to do it. That is doable too.